# How to get funding for research on something that can revolutionize the quantum world!

Tags: soft-question

I think [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/165038/14414) can revolutionize the quantum world! Any ideas on how to impress physicists to get a full fledged funding for research?

Comment: Well, I would naively say: first, PROOVE it indeed revolutionaries the quantum world, then wait 40-50 years, and you might potentially award the Nobel price. Note both steps require a lot of networking activities over the years, and the creation of a full school of students working on your idea. So,  I suggest you to start right now: **ask your neighbours at the lab, and see if they believe it's a revolutionary idea !**

Comment: Why and how should it revoluzionize the quantum world? Why should the quantum world need/be waiting for a "revolution" in the first place, as QM works perfectly well?

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of foundations that persistently pay millions of dollars to exactly the same kind of research that you are doing and the same kind of researchers (those who yell that they made a revolution but there is no visible beef that makes sense), namely – among many and many others – The Templeton Foundation, FQXi, and most departments of philosophies and various humanities and interdisciplinary studies that I will be happy to enumerate.